# Ubuntu Background Image doesn't stay at photo I want goes to black background

Tags: .desktop

Okay if question is double question or question has been answered my bad!

I am running Dual Boot, Ubuntu and Windows 10,

So on my Ubuntu desktop I want to change the background picture for the desktop, I am able, but after a time it changes back to Black Desktop Background.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Could you specify your Ubuntu Version?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't change the directory of the image
If Linux can't find your image path, it shows black on your background

Comment: yes true! most of the images are in a simple directory like my /home/pictures directory, so one would think it would be seen easy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the location the image is in doesn't change a lot. I had this same problem on Windows 10 and this fixed it for me.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I might just say forget it and just have the black desktop background!